# How to iterate through a folder of zipped .csv files to create & save multiple dataframes based on the unique values of a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, pyarrow

I'm setting up a data pipeline and need to start by preprocessing a set of zipped .csv files.  These are in a source folder and number ~3K.  Each zipped file represents a full day's worth of S&P 500 option data at 1 minute intervals which are denoted by a datetime stamp (e.g '5/24/2023  9:31:00 AM').  Most files have ~405 intervals, however some have less due to holiday schedules.   I need to iterate through each zipped file, creating a dataframe for each datetime interval and then save this to a target folder (as a parquet file) with the filename based on the datetime interval.  In total I expect ~1.2M parquet files.

I'm able to create a list of zipped files in my source folder which I verified by printing it out.

```
import glob
path = '.../source_folder'
files = glob.glob(path + '/*.zip')

print(files)
```

I'm also able to parse a single zipped .csv file using the following code:

*import dependencies*

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
import glob
from zipfile import ZipFile
```

*create dataframe from single .csv file using pyarrow as the engine*

```
daily_df = pd.read_csv('.../path.zip', compression = 'zip', engine = 'pyarrow')
```

*change directory to point the output to the target folder*

```
os.chdir('.../target_folder')
```

*iterate through the dataframe to create new dataframes based on unique values in 'quote_datetime' column & save to a parquet file*

```
for i, part_df in daily_df.groupby('quote_datetime'):
    part_df.to_csv(f'{i}.csv', index=False)
```

I need help with the following:

1. How do I iterate through a folder containing multiple zipped files vs just processing 1?
2. Is there anyway to vectorize this operation to speed it up?
3. The current code is converting a datetime value such as '5/24/2023  9:31:00 AM' to '2023-05-24 09/31/00'.  How do I maintain the time format so that it's either using colons or underscores...whichever is best practice?

Comment: It seems like perhaps `pyarrow.dataset` can do all this, but you can put the logic for processing 1 file into a function and use a ProcessPool to run the function on multiple files in parallel: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor 3. `.to_csv(date_format=....`)